# Dart - Flatten a list while removing duplicate values

Tags: dart

So, I have a list of lists, like this

```
var a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', 'b'], [3, 'd', true]];
```

I want to output a flattened list with duplicate values removed -

```
var b = ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 3, 'd', true];
```

While, I know I can use map/reduce, just trying to understand what is the most dart like way of doing this.

*More info about input - I'm just trying to understand iterables and sets better in Dart (coming from Python world).  Dart Trickeristry welcome!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to flatten the list of lists and remove duplicates.

The way to remove duplicates is to use a `Set` with an efficient lookup (or something equivalent, but `Set` is the simplest de-duplicating functionality).
Any other approach is likely going to be quadratic because it checks each element against each other element.

For that, I'd do:

```dart
var result = [...{for (var list in lists) ...list}];
```

This flattens the lists into a set, then converts that set to a list again.

The one other alternative would be flattening into a list, sorting the list, and then removing adjacent duplicates. That requires the elements to be [`Comparable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/Comparable-class.html), which the example given here isn't, or that you provide a comparison function. Let's assume the latter:

```dart
List<T> flatUnique(Iterable<Iterable<T>> elements, int compare(T a, T b)) {
  var flat = [for (var element in elements) ...element];
  if (flat.isEmpty) return flat;
  flat.sort(compare);
  var current = flat[0];
  var j = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i < flat.length; i++) {
    var next = flat[i];
    if (current != next) {
      current = flat[j++] = next;
    }
  }
  flat.length = j;
  return flat;
}
```

That's more complicated because there is not a general "remove duplicates from sorted list" operation in the libraries ... because people just use a set.

It also changes the order of elements other than by removing duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

in dart 2.3,

you can actually use spread operator like this:

```
var a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', 'b'], [3, 'd', true]];
var b = [...a[0], ...a[1], ...a[2]];
// print ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', 3, 'd', true];
```

and do your code afterwards

Comment: For removing the duplicates you could insert the values into a `Set` instead of a List.

Comment: Creating a set (which internally most likley is  map), I don't think that is going to be very performant.  Specially if this is a going to a large list

Comment: Listing each element of `a` individually won't scale well.  You instead can do `var b = [for (var i in a) ...i];`.

Comment: @Mahori Why don't you think a `Set` will be performant?  Using a `Set` should have roughly O(n) runtime complexity.  Space-wise, conceivably using the spread operator might be (temporarily) wasteful, but that's orthogonal to using a `Set`.  I suggest trying it first instead of prematurely optimizing.

Comment: @Mahori A set is constructed from a list in O(n) time. That's as efficient as it gets when it comes to removing duplicate values from a list. If you're worried about space efficiency, the spread operator approach is far more wasteful than a set will be. (The iterable approach is more space efficient, though. See my answer.)

Comment: If you are going to remove duplicates, then you need to check each element against each other element in some way. A set (in particular a *hash* set) is likely the most efficient way of doing that. I'd just do `[...{for (var list in lists) ...list}]`. This creates a set of the flattened lists, then converts that back to a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a `Set` with the `expand` method.

```dart
var a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', 'b'], [3, 'd', true]];
var b = Set.from(a.expand((x) => x)).toList();

// [a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, d, true]
```